# Comparison between Alfresco Installation Directory's and Eclipse IDE

Tags: alfresco-share

I have installed Alfresco 5.0 d version.
but while customization i am getting same file at different locations in alfresco installation directory. that is Shared directory inside tomcat folder and share, alfresco directory.

and if i have to use eclipse IDE, then i am not getting Which file to keep where?

please help me to compare all these things.

and also if we modify 1 file then all files with same name are get modified, so i am not getting that flow.

so please tell me how those files are override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below step.

1.Create maven project for share and alfresco.You need to create 2 different project.For share 1 and for alfresco 1

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/alfresco-sdk-cmd-reference.html
is link for creating alfresco and share project.

When you fire *mvn install*, that is going to take some time for downloading dependancies.

2.Create Webscript.
Below is link for that.
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ws-webscripts.html